# What's the purpose of this scene at the last?

Tags: plot-explanation, mollys-game

At the beginning of the movie *Molly's Game* (2017), Molly trips over a stick while skiing and
ends her skiing career. The scene then cuts to a hospital scene where
Molly is lying in bed.

But at the end of the movie, after Molly gets away from the legal case
with a small punishment and enjoys time with her family, the scene
cuts back to **the skiing incident where she tripped over the stick**.

What's the purpose of this scene at the last ?

Comment: No accident, no gaming life. When the latter ends, back to the former. Some circle of life?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This technique is a form of [circular storytelling](https://industrialscripts.com/circular-storytelling/):

> Circular storytelling is a structural technique visible in many stories across film, TV, literature and other mediums. In a circular narrative, the story ends where it began. Although the starting and ending points are the same, the character(s) undergo a transformation, affected by the story's events.
>
> By using a cyclical structure, writers can emphasize the knowledge gained during the course of the story. The audience can compare a character’s behaviour in the first and last scenes (and it makes for an even easier comparison if the scene is essentially the same) making the character’s journey clear as day.
>
> So circular narratives highlight in no uncertain terms your character’s progress.

As I said in a comment: *No accident, no gaming life. When the latter ends, back to the former. Some circle of life.*